# Bug in SAXON? It generates two adjacent text nodes for a leaf element

Tags: saxon

On the xml-dev list Michael Kay wrote:

> In the XDM model the content of the Test element
> is a single text node. XDM does not allow two
> adjacent text nodes.

I believe SAXON uses the XDM model.

Consider this leaf element:

```
<Test>
    abc<!-- aaa -->def
</Test>
```

I ran SAXON with this XSLT program:

```
<xsl:template match="Test">
    <xsl:message>count = <xsl:value-of select="count(text())"/></xsl:message>
</xsl:template>
```

The output is:

```
count = 2
```

That is not correct as it says the leaf element contains two adjacent text nodes, which clearly contradicts what Michael said on the xml-dev list. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you test that these two text nodes are adjacent? The `Test` element in the XDM has three child nodes, the first a text node, the second a comment node, the third another text node. So `count(text())` is 2.

Once you had `count(text()[following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]|preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]])` giving more than 0 there would be a wrong representation in the XDM.

It is possible with Saxon-JS and a JavaScript created DOM tree where you are able to create two separate text child nodes:

```js
const doc1 = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<root/>', 'application/xml');
doc1.documentElement.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode('Text child 1.'));
doc1.documentElement.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode('Text child 2.'));
console.log(doc1.documentElement.childNodes.length);

var result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`/*/count(text())`, doc1);

console.log(result);

var result2 = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`/*/count(text()[following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]|preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]])`, doc1);

console.log(result2);

doc1.normalize();

result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`/*/count(text())`, doc1);

console.log(result);

result2 = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`/*/count(text()[following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]|preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]])`, doc1);

console.log(result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>
```

But the `normalize` call on the document fixes that problem.